# Can't insert record into database using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert record into MySQL database using jQuery Ajax and PHP.My problem is that it is not inserted any row in the table. I tried this code:

For the html :

```
 `<script>
$(function(){
    //insert record
    $('#insert').click(function(){
        var jcomments_manager = $('#fcomments_manager').val();


        //syntax - $.post('filename', {data}, function(response){});
        $.post('data.php',{action: "insert", name:jcomments_manager},function(res){
            $('#result').html(res);
        });     
    });

    //show records
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $.post('data.php',{action: "show"},function(res){
            $('#result').html(res);
        });     
    });
});
</script>
Add a comment: <input type="text" id="fcomments_manager" />

            <button id="insert">Insert</button>
```

`

For the php :

```
`if($_POST['action'] == 'insert'){

    $comments_manager  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments_manager']);

    $c_id = $_GET['c_id'];

    $sql   = "INSERT INTO candidate (comments_manager) 
                VALUES ('$comments_manager')
               WHERE c_id = '$c_id'
               ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if($query){
        echo "Record Inserted.";
    }else {
        echo "Something Wrong!";
    }
}
```

`

Comment: There's no ?c_id=??? in the url/uri of $.post(), how can you get the $_GET['c_id'] ?

Comment: i get it from a table with all records per user, the url says that it takes it : http://localhost/dis/manager/add_comment.php?c_id=154

Answer (score 0):

You parameter names are mismatching

```
    //in server the manager parameter is read using name `comments_manager`, here you were passing it as name
    $.post('data.php',{action: "insert", comments_manager:jcomments_manager},function(res){
        $('#result').html(res);
    });
```

Comment: @user2703341 check the ajax request using your browsers developer tools network tab to see what data is being sent

Comment: I am new in programming, so can you explain me what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

`$comments_manager  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments_manager']);`

shouldn't that be:

`$comments_manager  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);`

Comment: Darnit. Arun was 9 seconds faster.

Comment: Ok I fixed that but I have same problem

Comment: As Ken Cheung mentioned, you should pass $_GET["c_id"] on to data.php, so make the $.post url "data.php". $_GET["c_id"]. I'd secure that GET value though if I were you.

Comment: can you post what exactly needs to to write?

Comment: `$.post('data.php?c_id='. $_GET["c_id"],{action: "insert", name:jcomments_manager}`